# Next Image with contentful asset 502 in upper envs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, contentful

When I try and load an next image using a contentful image source in upper environments it gets a 502 error. I have updated my next config with remotePatterns to handle this but it still gets a 502. Everything works fine on my local.

version: "next": "13.4.3",

```
const config = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'images.ctfassets.net',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/**',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

```
      case contentful.types.jumbotron: {
        const transformedJumbotronData = transformJumbotron(section.data);
        console.log('https:' + transformedJumbotronData.image.url);
        //logs out https://images.ctfassets.net/ABC123/Full_image.png
        const desktopImage = (
          <Image
            src={'https:' + transformedJumbotronData.image.url}
            width={500}
            height={500}
            alt={transformedJumbotronData.image.alt}
          />
        );
        sectionComponents.push(
          <Jumbotron
            key={index}
            ctaButtons={transformedJumbotronData.ctaButtons}
            desktopImage={desktopImage} //accepts JSX element
            title={transformedJumbotronData.title}
          />
        );
        br
```

[Image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7dub.png)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that next/image can only accept images at a certain resolution. So I made the image much smaller and then it worked.